# change facebook share button url dynamically

Tags: jquery, facebook

hi below is my code to change facebook share button dynamically

```
<script>
        function f1() {
            $(function () {
                var id = location.href.replace(/.*pid=/, '');
                $.galleriffic.gotoImage(id);
                { window.open("https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=" + escape(id) + "&t=" + document.title, '', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=300,width=600'); return false; }
               })
        };
    </script>

<div onclick="f1()" id="sharenew" class="fb-share-button" data-href=""></div>
```

in the given code facebook share button accept the url but i want to pass url with image id which get with # value so here my url become "http://writopedia.org/THCComment.aspx#2" but it does not accept by facebook so help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the given code is work for me

```
<script>
        function FBShareOp(){
            var product_name = jQuery("#title").val();
            var description =   jQuery("#description").html();
            var share_image =   jQuery("#share_image").attr('src');
            var share_url   =   jQuery("#share_url").attr('href');
            var share_capt = jQuery("#share_capt").val();
            var id = location.href.replace(/.*pid=/, '');
            $.galleriffic.gotoImage(id);
            FB.ui({
                method: 'feed',
                name: product_name,
                link: id,
                picture: images,
                caption: share_capt,
                description: description

            }, function(response) {
                if(response && response.post_id){}
                else{}
            });

        }
    </script>

<a onclick="FBShareOp();" style="color: #fff; background-color: #435EAB; padding: 2px 7px 1px 7px; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, 'lucida grande',tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif; font-size: 11px; text-decoration: none; border-radius: 2px; float: right; margin-top: 1px; margin-right: 45px;" href="#" title="Share" class="ymsb-fbshare-btn" data-target="popup" id="sharebutton">Share</a> &nbsp;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `FB.ui` share for dynamic URLs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog

Basic example from the docs:

```
FB.ui({
  method: 'share',
  href: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/',
}, function(response){});
```

Of course you need to include the JavaScript SDK for that: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart/v2.1

...and forget about the share button, just use your own button and call FB.ui on click.

Comment: thanks for the reply can u please advice me where do i put this code ?

Comment: you just call it in a click handler of your custom button, that´s all

Comment: i´ve added some information about the javascript sdk, you may want to read the links

Comment: it does not get http://writopedia.org/THCComment.aspx#2 because given url contain url with #

Comment: you should not use urls with an anchor then

Comment: i change your code by given code FB.ui(
                {
                    method: 'share',
                    href: 'http://writopedia.org/THCComment.aspx#4'
                    }, function (response) { });  but it does not work. please help me i am in more confusion.

Comment: "it does not work" is not a good error description...and check out the browser console if something does not work.

Comment: What if I want to do this but still have the generic Facebook share button?

Comment: then replace the generic share button with your own one ;)